# So how do I get rid of this email server from the dock and The Nautilus file manager?

Tags: command-line, delete

This server icon thing I cant get rid of it, I deleted the default keyrings so its useless and I Cant delete this icon. I am on ubuntu 22.10 On raspberry pi

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to Settings > Appearance [image: settings]
2. Scroll down until you see the last option about the Dock
   configuration
3. Click Configure Dock behaviour
4. Uncheck network volumes

[image: uncheck]

I do not know how to remove it from Nautilus other than removing your linked account.

Comment: Thanks man That was helpful :D

Comment: @adminfree You are very welcome! Remember to mark answers as solutions if they did, indeed, solve your problem :)